# Error in the proof? that $P(T=1\mid W=w)=\frac{w(n-w)}{n(n-1)}$

Tags: probability

Let $\{Y_i\}_{i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$ be independent Bernoulli Random Variables with parameter $p$.

First I had to show that if $T:=1$ if $Y_1=1,Y_2=0$ and $0$ otherwise, then $E(T)=p(1-p)$. That's done and it's a direct result of the definition of the expected value.
Then I had to show that if $W=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nY_i$, then $P(T=1\mid W=w)=\frac{w(n-w)}{n(n-1)}$. I did this:

"By definition of the conditional probability we have
$P(T=1\mid W=w)=\frac{P(T=1\wedge W=w)}{P(W=w)}$ and by multiplicative rule we get $P(T=1\mid W=w)=\frac{P(T=1)P(W=w\mid T=1)}{P(W=w)}$. We know that $P(T=1)=P(Y_1=1,Y_2=0)=P(Y_1=1)P(Y_2=0)=p(1-p)$ since they are independent.
And the event $W=w\mid T=1$ means that $\sum\limits_{i=3}^n Y_i=w-1$. Then the original probability becomes:
$P(T=1\mid W=w)=\frac{p(1-p)P(\sum\limits_{i=3}^n Y_i=w-1)}{P(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i=w)}$".

If I'm not mistaken, these probabilities are:

$P(\sum\limits_{i=3}^n Y_i=w-1)=(n-2)(n-3)\cdots(n-w+1)(n-w)p^{w-1}(1-p)^{n-w-1}$

$P(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i=w)=n(n-1)\cdots(n-w+1)p^w (1-p)^{n-w}$.

So the quotient becomes:
$P(T=1\mid W=w)=\frac{p(1-p)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots(n-w+1)(n-w)p^{w-1}(1-p)^{n-w-1}}{n(n-1)\cdots(n-w+1)p^w (1-p)^{n-w}}=\frac{(n-2)(n-3)\cdots(n-w+1)(n-w)p^{w}(1-p)^{n-w}}{n(n-1)\cdots(n-w+1)p^w (1-p)^{n-w}}=\frac{(n-w)}{n(n-1)}$.

The problem is that I'm missing a $w$ in the formula. What is wrong?

Also, Is the tag Ok? I thought it would perhaps be good the tag "Probability theory"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, by the definition of conditional probability, that
$$\Pr(T=1|W=w)=\frac{\Pr(T=1\cap W=w)}{\Pr(W=w)}.$$
The probability in the numerator is $p(1-p) \binom{n-2}{w-1}p^{w-1}(1-p)^{n-w-1}$. This is because the event $T=1\cap W=w$ happens if we have success, then failure, then $w-1$ successes in $n-2$ trials. For the probability of $w-1$ successes in $n-2$ trials we have used the standard binomial distribution probability mass function.

More simply, $\Pr(W=w)=\binom{n}{w}p^w (1-p)^{n-w}$. Divide. The terms in $p$ and $(1-p)$ cancel, and we end up with $\frac{\binom{n-2}{w-1}}{\binom{n}{w}}$.

The ratio of the binomial coefficients is
$$\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-w-1)!(w-1)!}\cdot\frac{w!(n-w)!}{n!}.$$
There is a lot of cancellation. For note that $\frac{w!}{(w-1)!}=w$ and $\frac{(n-w)!}{(n-w-1)!}=n-w$, and $\frac{(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$. We end up with $\frac{w(n-w)}{n(n-1)}$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the factorials in the fractions... thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Your method was essentially the same as mine, but the probabilities were not quite right. It is useful to stick to binomial coefficient and then  factorials until nearly the end.